# NHibernate Oracle CLOBs - very slow

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, clob

I have an NHibernate mapping on some tables in our Oracle 11g database, one of the tables contains a CLOB column. When attempting to query out ~10,000 rows of data, the query takes forever. When querying a subset of only 200 rows, the query ran for about 3 minutes. Mathematically this means it'll take 2.5 hours to query 10,000 rows.

If I remove the CLOB column from the NHibernate mapping, the same query takes ~3 seconds for 200 rows, and ~2 minutes for 10,000 rows.

Is this is just one of those 'by design' issues, either with the Oracle driver, or the way NHibernate handles CLOBs?

Comment: To be fair, if you are dealing with CLOB data, you shouldn't be manipulating large record sets.  If you need something fast and lightweight for this use case, Dapper + Managed ODP.NET is sure to net you a performance gain.

Comment: I don't think this is related with NHibernate. Have you tried lazy properties ? This way you can make that clob properties loaded one by one